# Working with RiakCS using erlcloud from elixir

Tags: ssl, elixir, riak

I want to use erlcloud to upload object to RiakCS, But it seems that erlcoud is using SSL by default. So I try to configure RiakCS to use SSL following the instruction from [basho's document](http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/configuration/Configuring-Riak-CS/#Enabling-SSL-in-Riak-CS).

```
stanchion_ssl = on
ssl.certfile = "./cert.pem"
ssl.keyfile = "./key.pem"
```

But I dont have the luck to make erlcloud to work with RiakCS after following the instructions [here](http://blog.jordan-dimov.com/accessing-the-amazon-aws-from-elixir-using-erlcloud/)

```
iex(1)> access_key_id = System.get_env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") |> String.to_char_list

iex(2)> secret_access_key = System.get_env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY") |> String.to_char_list

iex(3)> endpoint = System.get_env("IDCF_ENDPOINT") |> String.to_char_list

iex(4)> port = System.get_env("IDCF_PORT") |> String.to_integer
8080
iex(6)> :erlcloud_s3.configure(access_key_id, secret_access_key, endpoint, port)
:ok

iex(7)> :erlcloud_s3.create_bucket('test2.media')
** (ErlangError) erlang error: {:aws_error, {:socket_error, {:nxdomain, [{:lhttpc_client, :send_request, 1, [file: 'src/lhttpc_client.erl', line: 222]}, {:lhttpc_client, :execute, 9, [file: 'src/lhttpc_client.erl', line: 171]}, {:lhttpc_client, :request, 9, [file: 'src/lhttpc_client.erl', line: 93]}]}}}
(erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:1036: :erlcloud_s3.s3_request/8
(erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:1005: :erlcloud_s3.s3_simple_request/8

iex(7)> :erlcloud_s3.create_bucket('test5')
** (ErlangError) erlang error: {:aws_error, {:socket_error, :connection_closed}}
(erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:1036: :erlcloud_s3.s3_request/8
(erlcloud) src/erlcloud_s3.erl:1005: :erlcloud_s3.s3_simple_request/8
iex(7)>
```

after checking out the lhttpc_client file's line 222

it seems like a SSL problem. But I just cannot figure it out.

Maybe I should figure out how to configure SSL in a general way?

For example, make nginx work with SSL?